# Everything I run my code on android studio, I get these set of errors, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, compilation

****activity_main.xml code****

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="From Riya"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Imageview
        android:src="@drawable/party_pic"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

"ERRORS":

```
07/02 20:41:18: Launching 'app' on Pixel XL API 27.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "android.example.birthdaycard/android.example.birthdaycard.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 9243 on device 'Pixel_XL_API_27 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.example.birthdaycard, PID: 9243
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.example.birthdaycard/android.example.birthdaycard.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Imageview
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Imageview
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Imageview
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Imageview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/android.example.birthdaycard-vHuLF8O8-BA_mn_tr83zVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/android.example.birthdaycard-vHuLF8O8-BA_mn_tr83zVw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.example.birthdaycard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

MainActivity.java code

```
package android.example.birthdaycard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android. os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've mistyped `Imageview`. It should be `ImageView`, Java is case-sensitive. When you get an error like yours - *Didn't find class "android.view.Imageview"*, always double check your spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `View`s must be present inside some `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From Riya" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/party_pic" />
</LinearLayout>
```